# emacs 24.4.1 cannot create frame when monitor is off

Tags: emacs, freeze, monitor, emacs24, power-saving

I used version 24.3.1 before. Some my script run `emacsclient -c` by the schedule when monitor is off to save power: everything was ok. But there is a problem with new version 24.4.1 - emacs freezes until the monitor is on (by keboard or mouse) and only after that it wakes up and creates frame.

---

GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2) of 2014-10-21 on kairos
Linux kairos 3.7.0-030700-generic #201212102335 SMP Tue Dec 11 04:36:24 UTC 2012
Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Comment: This doesn't really help, but why are you making frames if your monitor isn't on? Wouldn't you be better off running emacs in batch mode or something, if you're doing elisp based scripting?

Comment: If I run my script without frame then it works wrong, I don't know exactly why.